# Md5 and Salt in Mysql

Tags: mysql, cryptography

how can "decode" the password stored in various e-commerce adding "salt". I'm not crypth experts... so, in past, i used something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=@email AND passwd=MD5(@pwd)
```

MySql MD5 function accept only one parameter... How can i do if i have a Salt string ?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of salt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051007/what-is-the-purpose-of-salt)

Comment: I don't think it's possible, even if you have the salt.

Comment: MD5 is not good for hashing passwords, and a salt just makes it barely better: [http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/13877](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/13877)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a column in mytable called salt and then retrieve this value when creating the MD5 Hash:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=@email AND passwd=MD5(salt + ':' +@pwd)
```

When inserting the record you would do:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(email, salt, passwd)
VALUES (@email, @salt, MD5(salt + ':' + @pwd)
```

Answer (score 4):

Salt is a  string you add to the beginning of text which should be encrypted.

Do it like: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=@email AND passwd=MD5(CONCAT(@salt, @pwd))`

Comment: Usually in my applications I assume that salt is constant. Of course you can keep it in a table.

Comment: If the salt is constant then this will eliminate the purpose of salt. If I use the password: secret on my website and somehow I was able to gain access to your database. I could easily see which other users also have chosen the same password: secret; since the MD5 hash would be identical.

Comment: True, but what's the possibility of this kind of event?
Assume situation: attacker compromises database and gets tons of MD5, salt remains secret. If salt is long enough, he won't be able to decode all of them in a reasonable time.
But when there's a per-user salt, if user's password is short enough, he'll be able to crack it. Please note, that I'm not a cryptography expert and I will be thankful to you for correcting me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That logic should be in the application, then you'll simply compare the calculated value against what's stored in the database.

(If not in the application, you *could* use functions in MySQL, but I wouldn't recommend that approach. I like to keep all application logic in one place if possible, not spread in different parts.)

If you run functions like that in the `WHERE` clauses of your query, MySQL will be unable to use an index on `passwd` because it has to calculate something for every value in the `passwd` column. Instead, do your salting and hashing in your application, then compare that final string against your stored info in a plain query that can use an index, like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE email=@email AND passwd=@pwdhash
```

Comment: Why the one downvote? If I'm wrong about something, please point it out. I'm here to learn, too. :-)